# Is the color hue of a variable in VS Code telling me something?

Tags: python, numpy, variables, visual-studio-code

I have noticed a little curiosity in VS Code with a Python script I am writing:

I have some function that returns a `numpy` matrix `B` along with a list of parameters called `parameters`. In the editor, the blue hue of `B` is a slightly darker color than the one for `parameters`. This also happens for all caps variable names, like `ABC`, but not when starting with a capital letters and then switching to lowercase, or for a single character lowercase variable name like `b`.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: original]

[image: all caps]

[image: one letter, lowercase]

[image: Capital starting letter]

Zooming in on this screenshot confirms that the colors are slightly different (''dark'' blue is `#44c1ff` with a `#1e59c5` shadow, while the lighter blue is `#7cdcf0` with a `#1e1ea7` shadow).

My question is: is VS Code trying to tell me something with this slight color discrepancy? Am I violating some variable naming guidelines unknowingly?

What I tried: Changed variable names around, got different color hues, code executes the same regardless of color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) specifies these relevant naming conventions:

- `lowercase` for variable names
- `CapWords` for class names
- `UPPERCASE` for constants

VS Code is highlighting constants differently.